# Is it possible to install LinuxMint's IPTV application named Hypnotix on Ubuntu from deb-package?

Tags: 20.04, package-management, software-installation, 21.10, mint

LinuxMint ships IPTV application named Hypnotix with 2.6 version.

> Hypnotix is an IPTV streaming application with support for live TV, movies and series.
> [image: shadow]

Sources: https://github.com/linuxmint/hypnotix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways to install Hypnotix - compilation and binary deb-package installation as follows:

- Compilation from sources on 20.04 LTS and 21.10 is done by:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install git debhelper
  cd ~/Downloads
  git clone https://github.com/linuxmint/hypnotix -b 2.6
  cd hypnotix
  dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
  sudo apt-get install ../hypnotix_2.6_all.deb
  ```
- Binary package installation from [“Wasta-Linux” team Cinnamon-Testing PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewasta-linux/+archive/ubuntu/cinnamon-testing?field.series_filter=focal).

  On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS the above PPA should be added in simple way:

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:wasta-linux/cinnamon-testing
  ```

  Note: for Ubuntu 21.10 additional step is needed - `sudo sed -i "s/impish/focal/g" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wasta-linux-ubuntu-cinnamon-testing-impish.list`

  Then update package lists, allow installation of only one Hyphotix package and install it by:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update

  cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-hypnotix
  Package: *
  Pin: release o=LP-PPA-wasta-linux-cinnamon-testing
  Pin-Priority: -1

  Package: hypnotix
  Pin: release o=LP-PPA-wasta-linux-cinnamon-testing
  Pin-Priority: 1000
  EOF

  sudo apt-get install hypnotix
  ```

  To revert the changes use the following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install aptitude ppa-purge
  sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-hypnotix
  sudo ppa-purge ppa:wasta-linux/cinnamon-testing
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  ```

---

Possible alternative with easier installation is [Astroncia IPTV](https://gitlab.com/astroncia/iptv), it is installable from [its PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eastroncia/+archive/ubuntu/iptv) for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and newer versions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:astroncia/iptv
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install astroncia-iptv
```

It has favourites functionality.